# Showing $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt i}>\sqrt n$ by induction.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing, induction

I need to prove this inequality by using induction: $(\frac{1}{\sqrt1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{n}$ for $n\geq2$.

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt i}>\sqrt n$$

I easily get by the base case for $n=2$, you get $2 > 1/4$, which is true. Then you make the assumption to be true for $(1/\sqrt1) + (1/\sqrt2) + (1/\sqrt3) +...+ (1/\sqrt n)) > \sqrt n$

And then you have to prove for $(1/\sqrt1) + (1/\sqrt2) + (1/\sqrt3) +...+ (1/\sqrt n ) + (1/\sqrt{n+1}) > \sqrt{n+1} .$

I don't know where to go from here. any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: your argument for the base case ($2>1/4$) looks incorrect to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the inductive step, you need $\sqrt n+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}$.

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n+1}$:

$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}+1>n+1.$$

Can you prove it now?

(Hint:  subtract $1$ from both sides.)

Comment: Sorry for my dumb-ass brain, but can you elaborate more, what it means in plain English after subtracting 1 from both side?

Comment: I meant can you prove $\sqrt{n(n+1)}>n$?

Comment: ........... no :/

Comment: how about squaring both sides ($n^2+n>n^2$), or $\sqrt{n(n+1)}>\sqrt{n(n)}=n$?

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit, answer and explanation! i get it now.
Really appreciate you :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

So what we have to prove is:

$$\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n+1}$$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} =
\frac{n+1 - n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$